# css submenu ul li problems

Tags: html, css, superfish

I have a menu using SuperFish but the last 2 submenu's do not align up properly.

Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uP4bY/4/

My CSS looks like this:

```
    /*  Header/Navigation   */
 div#Nav {
    background:transparent url(../Images/nav_Bg.png) no-repeat scroll top left;
    height:70px;
    width:980px;
    margin:0 auto;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
}
/*Level 1 or Parent / Destination*/
 div#Nav ul {
    padding-top:9px;
    display:inline;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
}
div#Nav ul li {
    background:transparent url(../Images/nav_li_Separator.png) no-repeat scroll center left;
    padding-left:8px;
    margin-left:8px;
    display:inline;
    position:relative;
}
div#Nav ul li.First {
    background:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
/*Level 2 Treks*/
 div#Nav ul li ul {
    left:10px;
    position:absolute;
    top:26px;
    padding:0 !important;
    z-index:100;
    height:500px;
    float:left;
    list-style:outside;
    width:auto;
}
/*Level 3 Everest Region*/
 div#Nav ul li ul li ul {
    float: left;
    height: 500px;
    left: 50px;
    list-style: disc outside none;
    padding: 0 !important;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    width: auto;
    z-index: 100;
}
/*Level 5 Everest Base Camp*/
 div#Nav ul ul ul ul ul {
    float: left;
    height: 500px;
    left: 50px;
    list-style: disc outside none;
    padding: 0 !important;
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    width: auto;
    z-index: 100;
}
div#Nav ul li ul li {
    border-top:1px solid #2f3b48;
    border-right:1px solid #384857;
    border-bottom:1px solid #384857;
    height:24px;
    display:block;
    padding:5px 15px 0;
    width:150px;
    /*width:150px;*/
    border-left:1px solid #384857;
    margin:0 !important;
    background:transparent url(http://www.kenticotemplates.net/themeforest/DreamTravel/Images/Nav_ul_li_Bg.png) repeat scroll top left !important;
}
div#Nav a, div#Nav a:link, div#Nav a:visited {
    color:#7f8b98;
}
div#Nav a:hover, div#Nav a.selected {
    color:#96b2cb !important;
    text-decoration:none;
}
div#Nav ul#Links, div#Nav ul.nav {
    float:left;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
div#Nav ul.Lang {
    float:right;
}
div#Nav ul li {
    float:left;
}
```

I am pretty certain i need to style the last `ul li` but when i do this it moves the previous ul li.

**UPDATE: it should look like this minus the white space!**
http://i48.tinypic.com/1zfpxqf.png

Comment: Your fiddle isn't working for me (all items are shown), and you're missing quotes on <ul style="display:none;">.

Comment: its not meant to work... Just need to align the sub menu UL's....

Comment: It's cleaner to use the `>` selector in this case like `#Nav>ul>li>ul` and so on.

Comment: I see... @LinusCaldwell what does that selector do? parent child ???

Comment: Yes, it's the child selector. `#Nav > ul` will address just the `ul` directly under your `#nav`, but not the next one inside the `ul > li`. Read more: http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/

Comment: what is it meant to look like as they line up as your css describes - 50px to the left of the parent and 30px from the top (60 in the case of the last ul which is why you have the white space)

Comment: @Pete it should be similar to the others at the beginning... Less the white space..

Comment: cant seem to add a picture as i need 10 rep points :( ... But here is what it should look like minus the white space: http://i48.tinypic.com/1zfpxqf.png

Comment: I am stuck... i dont know which part of the code i should put the `>` syntax..

Comment: @PriceCheaperton please have look on my answer. The css you want is there in my answer and see demo fiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution of problem is her in fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/7mvuw/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7mvuw/embedded/result/

Note: I have changed the looks and feel but  html structure is same, looks and feel for demo purpose you can adjust as per your requirement.

[image]

```
#access {
    background: #000;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 940px;
}
#access .menu-header,
div.menu {
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-left: 12px;
    width: 928px;
}
#access .menu-header ul,
div.menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
}
#access .menu-header li,
div.menu li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
#access a {
    color: #aaa;
    display: block;
    line-height: 38px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#access ul ul {
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 38px;
    left: 0;
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
    z-index: 99999;
    padding-left:0;
}
#access ul ul li {
    min-width: 180px;
}
#access ul ul ul {
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
#access ul ul a {
    background: #333;
    line-height: 1em;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 160px;
    height: auto;
}
#access li:hover > a,
#access ul ul :hover > a {
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
}
#access ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
#access ul li.current_page_item > a,
#access ul li.current-menu-ancestor > a,
#access ul li.current-menu-item > a,
#access ul li.current-menu-parent > a {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much!  Very clean code.. I have learned alot in your examples. Thank you again! You are are great!

Comment: Dhan'yavāda bhā'ī, āpa apanē na'ē dōsta haiṁ

Comment: Hi priceCheaperton you are the first person who tried to talk in hindi with me on SO. cool man off course i will be glad to make friend ship with you. Thx alot for response. I hope your problem solved finally.